# How to turn shadows to low when packaging in Unreal?

Tags: build, package, lag, shadows

We're making a game in Unreal 4, and when playing the game in editor it was very laggy until we went to Engine Scalability Settings and turned shadows to low. Then it ran fine. But when we export the project, it looks like shadows are still on, and the game lags really bad, like 5 frames per second. How do I make the packaged build use the low shadows setting?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get rid of the lagging shadows, we had a bunch of tree meshes made with the foliage brush and they were all casting shadows, so I turned the shadows on those off. (Under the foliage brush in the Modes panel, clicked Show Instance and there were "cast shadow" checkboxes we unchecked. Got rid of the lag completely.